# PayPal Agreement Amount getting Doubled on Creation Issue

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I have an issue with the Paypal Agreement creation. The amount entered is getting doubled in agreement.

```
        PaymentDefinition paymentDefinition = new PaymentDefinition();
        paymentDefinition.setName("Regular Payments");
        paymentDefinition.setType("REGULAR");

        paymentDefinition.setFrequencyInterval("1");
        paymentDefinition.setCycles("12");

        // Currency
        Currency currency = new Currency();
        currency.setCurrency("USD");
        currency.setValue("5");
        paymentDefinition.setAmount(currency);


        ChargeModels chargeModels = new ChargeModels();
        chargeModels.setType("SHIPPING");
        chargeModels.setAmount(currency);
        List<ChargeModels> chargeModelsList = new ArrayList<ChargeModels>();
        chargeModelsList.add(chargeModels);
        paymentDefinition.setChargeModels(chargeModelsList);

        MerchantPreferences merchantPreferences = new MerchantPreferences();
        merchantPreferences.setSetupFee(currency);
```

Agreement created image is attached showing double the amount.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. I need to remove chargeModels list from paymentDefinition. ChargeModels are just to add miscellaneous charges like shipping/tax. Its added by PayPal examples by default to just show we can add such charges too.